# Cast vector of i8 to vector of u8 in Rust?

Tags: string, vector, casting, rust

Is there a better way to cast `Vec<i8>` to `Vec<u8>` in Rust except for these two?

1. creating a copy by mapping and casting every entry
2. using `std::transmute`

The (1) is slow, the (2) is "transmute should be the absolute last resort" according to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html).

A bit of background maybe: I'm getting a `Vec<i8>` from the unsafe [gl::GetShaderInfoLog()](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glGetShaderInfoLog) call and want to create a string from this vector of chars by using `String::from_utf8()`.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://github.com/nukep/rust-opengl-util/blob/fc30c6e386b0a4510564f242d995c845472207d3/shader.rs#L56

Comment: Is this code you'll call that often it is worth messing around with such unsafe mechanisms like transmute and from_raw_parts? Usually you don't (re)compile shaders all that often...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The other answers provide excellent solutions for the underlying problem of creating a string from `Vec<i8>`. To answer the question as posed, creating a `Vec<u8>` from data in a `Vec<i8>` can be done without copying or transmuting the vector. As pointed out by @trentcl, transmuting the vector directly constitutes undefined behavior because `Vec` is allowed to have different layout for different types.

The correct (though still requiring the use of `unsafe`) way to transfer a vector's data without copying it is:

- obtain the `*mut i8` pointer to the data in the vector, along with its length and capacity
- leak the original vector to prevent it from freeing the data
- use [`Vec::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts) to build a new vector, giving it the pointer cast to `*mut u8` - this is the unsafe part, because we are vouching that the pointer contains valid and initialized data, and that it is not in use by other objects, and so on.

This is not UB because the new `Vec` is given the pointer of the correct type from the start. Code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06dc44f5a36c7edf42ff8d9252d4f2ec)):

```rust
fn vec_i8_into_u8(v: Vec<i8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    // ideally we'd use Vec::into_raw_parts, but it's unstable,
    // so we have to do it manually:

    // first, make sure v's destructor doesn't free the data
    // it thinks it owns when it goes out of scope
    let mut v = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(v);

    // then, pick apart the existing Vec
    let p = v.as_mut_ptr();
    let len = v.len();
    let cap = v.capacity();
    
    // finally, adopt the data into a new Vec
    unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(p as *mut u8, len, cap) }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![-1i8, 2, 3];
    assert!(vec_i8_into_u8(v) == vec![255u8, 2, 3]);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, "slight" correction: pointer casts (+ `from_raw_parts`) are not just "slightly safer" than `transmute`, because (AIUI) `transmute` from `Vec<T>` to `Vec<U>` is always undefined behavior. Both use `unsafe`, but `from_raw_parts` is *correct*, while `transmute` is *incorrect*.

Comment: @trentcl Thanks, I've updated the answer. (Here I meant to compare the cast to transmuting the _pointer_, an idea which I had in an early draft of the answer, and removed before posting it.) However, I'm curious exactly _why_ would transmute from `Vec<i8>` to `Vec<u8>` be UB, while creating a new `Vec<u8>` from the pointer obtained with a cast from `*mut i8` to `*mut u8` is kosher? Is it because the representation of `Vec<T>` might depend on the type of `T` in the future, or is there something makes it UB wrt current Rust's or LLVM's abstract machine models?

Comment: Just because the representation of `Vec<T>` may depend on `T`. It's not likely, but it is allowed. I confess I find it hard to imagine a situation where this would be a useful thing to exploit.

Comment: @trentcl Agreed, `Vec` is probably not the best example, but I can imagine a data structure storing information about a generic type, for example to prevent code explosion from monomorphization. Still, I wonder how far one could take the caution. For example, is it UB to pass `Vec<u8>::from_raw_parts` a `*mut u8` pointer whose data was originally allocated through a reques for `*mut i8`? It would help if there were clearer documentation as to what constitutes UB in unsafe Rust.

Answer (score 11):

`transmute` on a `Vec` is always, 100% wrong, causing undefined behavior, because the layout of `Vec` is not specified. However, as the page you linked also mentions, you can use raw pointers and `Vec::from_raw_parts` to perform this correctly. [user4815162342's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707887/3650362) shows how.

([`std::mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) is the only item in the Rust standard library whose documentation consists mostly of suggestions for how **not** to use it. Take that how you will.)

However, in this case, `from_raw_parts` is also unnecessary. The best way to deal with C strings in Rust is with the wrappers in [`std::ffi`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/index.html), `CStr` and `CString`. There may be better ways to work this in to your real code, but here's one way you could use `CStr` to borrow a `Vec<c_char>` as a `&str`:

```
const BUF_SIZE: usize = 1000;
let mut info_log: Vec<c_char> = vec![0; BUF_SIZE];
let mut len: usize;
unsafe {
    gl::GetShaderInfoLog(shader, BUF_SIZE, &mut len, info_log.as_mut_ptr());
}
let log = Cstr::from_bytes_with_nul(info_log[..len + 1])
    .expect("Slice must be nul terminated and contain no nul bytes")
    .to_str()
    .expect("Slice must be valid UTF-8 text");
```

Notice there is no `unsafe` code except to call the FFI function; you could also use `with_capacity` + `set_len` (as in [wasmup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707569/3650362)) to skip initializing the `Vec` to 1000 zeros, and use `from_bytes_with_nul_unchecked` to skip checking the validity of the returned string.

Answer (score 2):

1. See [this](https://github.com/nukep/rust-opengl-util/blob/fc30c6e386b0a4510564f242d995c845472207d3/shader.rs#L64):

```
fn get_compilation_log(&self) -> String {
    let mut len = 0;
    unsafe { gl::GetShaderiv(self.id, gl::INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &mut len) };
    assert!(len > 0);

    let mut buf = Vec::with_capacity(len as usize);
    let buf_ptr = buf.as_mut_ptr() as *mut gl::types::GLchar;
    unsafe {
        gl::GetShaderInfoLog(self.id, len, std::ptr::null_mut(), buf_ptr);
        buf.set_len(len as usize);
    };

    match String::from_utf8(buf) {
        Ok(log) => log,
        Err(vec) => panic!("Could not convert compilation log from buffer: {}", vec),
    }
}
```

---

2. See ffi:

```
let s = CStr::from_ptr(strz_ptr).to_str().unwrap();
```

[Doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html)