# How to access a Vector of newtypes as the underlying type

Tags: vector, rust, casting

I have a newtype:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
pub struct Foo(pub u32);
```

and a vector of them:

```
let v: Vec<Foo> = Vec::new();
```

I need a read-only reference to `v` as `Vec<u32>`.

How can I do this without wastefully making a new vector?

And the reverse?

My current workaround involves creating a new vector:

```
foo_vec.iter().map(|x| x.0).collect()
```

```
u32_vec.iter().map(|x| Foo(*x)).collect()
```

I assume that the compiler isn't clever enough to optimise these away, even with `#[repr(transparent)]`.

Comment: A shared reference to a `Vec` doesn't make much sense because you can't mutate it anyway. You probably need a _slice_, which you can obtain with `slice::from_raw_parts(v.ptr() as *u32, v.len())`. This is of course highly unsafe because Rust will not be able to enforce aliasing rules, you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: @user4815162342 You're right, I'm happy to drop the old Vec to make a new one.

Comment: That makes things less unsafe, as long as it's allowed to cast between the types. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59707887/1600898) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the definition of `Foo`, then you can't because there is no guarantee that `Foo` has the same memory representation as `u32`.

If you can change the definition of `Foo`, then you need to add [`#[repr(transparent)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprtransparent) to it:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord)]
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct Foo(pub u32);
```

Now you can use [`std::mem::transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) to convert between `Foo` and `u32`:

```
let u32_val: u32 = mem::transmute(Foo(42));
let foo_val: Foo = mem::transmute(u32_val);
```

I'm not sure how that translates to transmuting `Vec`s, though. It will probably work, but I don't think it is guaranteed (it's probably undefined behaviour).

Comment: In this case `Vec::<Foo>::from_raw_parts` should be equivalent of transmuting. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts

Comment: @Jmb That works, but it is only allowed in an `unsafe` block or function, so I'll stick with `.iter().map()` unless there's a safe way around this.

Comment: @justinas That also requires `unsafe`, which is not ideal.